# Is a solution possible using stars and bars approach for this combination problem?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

There are two pieces of Almonds cake, eight Apple pie and two Key lime pie in a dessert case. How many different outcomes are possible if a person needs to pick a dessert for his two friends and himself?

I tried to solve it by using the formula C(3+3-1 , 3) = 10  and the condition that 2 of the desserts can only be given to two individuals giving the final answer of 8, and this clearly looks incorrect.

Comment: Seems [right](https://tio.run/##PcgxDoAgDEDR3VOYOFCQOOjiHWTgCqgkNpGWQBdPj3Fx@nk/P3Ixza1hylykR4lFmO/a5YIkUKPA/6aD044UBJkqgHLKzHoE5ZVZv26f7aK17obgEtNpg893tFt8WnsB) if you're picking an unordered set of $3$ deserts.

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin and if it is an ordered set how do we proceed?

Comment: $3!$ for different, then $2\cdot{3\choose 2}\cdot{3\choose 1}$ for $2$+$1$ and then $1$ for 3 apple pies yeilds [$25$](https://tio.run/##TY7BagMhEIbP9SmEsjiTyh7SSwn0CZJD7mkOsrrURh3R2UD68lttQ@hp/g9@vvnzjT8pbdfVx0yFpWdXmChUMReKcqIQ3MSeUpX3hnWzWQJbP7Gw7/8IqmMUMxXppU@yETxsY3YlLmx@TQDqoDZbfAF1VJu3fved9SviTjzZU3v97VIXBF@bBfE8GmtbEM/mEClZbY45OL13N5GLTwzqI6nxi3wCNdSdHKoaoHIBXloPLoi600ndSx7lY@j1jH900dfOdmyzYwVEXNcf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer counts the number of ways three desserts could be selected from the desserts available in the display case.  However, it matters which person receives which dessert.

If there were at least three pies of each type, then there would be three choices for each individual, so there would be $3^3$ ways of selecting a pie for each person.  However, we cannot give all three people a piece of almond cake, nor can we give all three people a piece of key lime pie.  Hence, there are $3^3 - 2 = 25$ ways for the person to select a dessert for his two friends and himself.

Answer (score 1):

I would approach it by breaking it down in to elementary cases.

Case A: Everybody gets apple pie.
${ N(A)=1 }$ is pretty obvious.

Case B: Everybody gets a different dessert. ${N(B)=3!=6}$

Case C: Two friends get same dessert and one friend gets something else. 
Since two friends get the same thing, select one friend in ${{3}\choose{1}}$ ways who gets a different kind of dessert from the other two. The first two guys have three choices and the last guy has two choices in any case(He cannot have the same thing since it is covered in case A) and hence ${N(C)={{3}\choose{1}}*{{3}\choose{1}}*{{2}\choose{1}}}$ ways.

Hence total number of ways in which they can have their desserts is $1+6+18=25$ ways